Intuition on Kolmogorov 3 Series Theorem
This is rather general question and there might be no such thing as a right answer, but I would admire any replies.
Prelude
Recall that

Khintchine-Kolmogorov Theorem:
if $X_i$ are independent and $L^2$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$, and $\sum\mathrm{Var}(X_i)<+\infty$, then $\sum X_i$ converges a.s.

The statement of the above and of the 3 Series Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) and their practical usefulness (given by the fact it is essentially a characterization, for independent r.v.s) is very clear. The problem is I don't really get the conditions.
In the former, if we wanted the series to have finite variance then it would make sense to ask that $\sum\mathrm{Var}(X_i)<+\infty$, as by independence it holds
$$
\sum^n\mathrm{Var}(X_i) =\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum^n X_i\right).
$$
But actually, nothing really stops the series (which is a limit) to have infinite variance, while still converging a.s.. Moreover, if we look the other way around it, why should the limit having finite variance imply that the a.s. convergence is guaranteed?
The question
Thus, the request the theorem makes doesn't really make much sense to me. With the 3 Series Theorem it gets only worse, obviously. I am therefore looking for intuition on these hypothesis. Thank you.


if we look the other way around it, why should the limit having finite variance imply that the a.s. convergence is guaranteed?

Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$.
Then see that for any $n,m$ such that $m>n$
\begin{align}||S_{n}-S_{m}||_{L^{2}}^{2}:=E(|S_{n}-S_{m}|^{2})&=Var(S_{n}-S_{m})\\\\&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}Var(X_{k})\\\\&\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}Var(X_{k})\end{align}
The above goes to $0$ as $n,m\to\infty$ when $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Var(X_{k})<\infty$.
This shows that the sequence $(S_{n})$ is Cauchy in the $L^{2}$-norm. Now if you know a bit of Hilbert Space Theory(or basic Measure Theory), then you would know that the space of square integrable random variables defined on a probability space equipped with the $L^{2}$-norm i.e. $||X||=(E(|X|^{2}))^{1/2}$ is a complete metric space.
This ensures that the limit of $S_{n}$ in the $L^{2}$-sense exists. i.e. there exists an square integrable random variable $Y$ such that  $E(|S_{n}-Y|^{2})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ .
You must also know that convergence in mean implies convergence in Probability, i.e. apply Chebycheff/Markov's Inequality to get
$$P(|S_{n}-Y|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|S_{n}-Y|^{2})}{\epsilon^{2}}$$
Thus you also have that $S_{n}\xrightarrow{P} Y$.
Now, the question is where do you get almost sure convergence from, as both convergence in mean and convergence in probability are not enough to show convergence almost surely for general random variables.
Here is where a theorem of Levy comes in which says that if $S_{n}$ is the sum of independent random variables $X_{k}$, then $S_{n}$ converges in Probability if and only if $S_{n}$ converges almost surely.
Combining all of these, I think you have enough reason to intuitively expect why the Theorem/Criterion works.
There are other ways to prove this by using Martingale Theory. In this case, $S_{n}$ becomes a $L^{2}$-bounded Martingale and hence it will converge both almost surely and in $L^{2}$ to some square integrable random variable due to Martingale Convergence Theorem.

On the otherhand, this theorem only gives a sufficient condition. For example, the sum of variance might diverge but still you may have almost sure convergence of the series.

But actually, nothing really stops the series (which is a limit) to have infinite variance, while still converging a.s.

Let $X_{n}$ be independent and distributed as follows:
$P(X_{n}=n^{2})=\frac{1}{2n^{2}}$, $P(X_{n}=-n^{2})=\frac{1}{2n^{2}}$ and $P(X_{n}=0)=(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}})$.
Then $E(X_{n})=0$ and $Var(X_{n})=n^{2}$.
But, you have $P(X_{n}\neq 0)= \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $\sum_{n}P(X_{n}\neq 0)<\infty$.
Thus, the Borel-Cantelli Lemma gives you that almost surely, all but finitely many $X_{n}$ will take value $0$.
Thus $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ will almost surely converge even though, the sum of variances diverges, i.e. the series has infinite variance.
In fact, the variance need not even exist for $X_{k}$. Let $\mu$ be a distribution with mean $0$ but infinite variance. Example of such a variate/distribution is easy to make. Just take $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ to be your probability space and let $Z(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}-2$ for $\omega\in[0,1]$. Then the distribution $\mu_{Z}$ will have the said properties.
Now define $X_{n}$ to be independent and having probability distribution $\frac{1}{n^{2}}\mu_{Z}+(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}})\delta_{0}$. Here $\delta_{0}$ refers to the Dirac Delta measure at $0$. Then $X_{n}$'s have infinite variance but still $\sum_{n}X_{n}$ converges almost surely due to the Borel-Cantelli Lemma akin to what we have shown previously.

That's awesome. Thank you!

@SimoneLicciardi Glad I could help.
